# WINAPI Button background

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, win32gui

In WINAPI, I create a button like:

```
case WM_CREATE:
{
    Start = CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_TRANSPARENT, "Button", "Start", WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | BS_PUSHBUTTON, 20, 50, 75, 25, window, (HMENU)ID_START, hInstance, NULL);
            break;
}
```

The button looks like:
[image]

But I need it to look like this one (which I did in .Net):

[image]

How can I get rid of that black border/background?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
  Start = CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_TRANSPARENT, ...);
```

You got the black outline because you used the WS_EX_TRANSPARENT style flag.  It isn't clear why you used it, there's not much you can do with it when you use the Button control.  It is otherwise probably the [least understood style flag](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2012/12/17/10378525.aspx).  Pass 0 instead to get a normal looking button.

It is otherwise a lost cause to get the *exact* look of a .NET button, Winforms doesn't use the built-in Button control.  It creates its own, using a custom renderer to get the  gradient look.  Reproducing that native code is a lot of work.

Comment: Can you explain how WS_EX_TRANSPARENT changes the appearance of the border? I didn't think it would have any affect on the appearance at all. Have to agree with you on it being misunderstood.

Comment: No idea, never considered trying this until a half hour ago.  It looks like it skips WM_ERASEBKGND, not unusual for transparency simulation.

Comment: You're right. When I remove the transparent flag, it puts a grey border instead.. I made it transparent so that it won't be grey like in this image: http://i.imgur.com/sgcE4.png

Comment: Well, you found out .NET doesn't use it.  Why it doesn't implement WM_CTLCOLORBTN either is another one of life's mysteries I long ago put in the forget-about-it box.  Raw user32 is just not productive.  If you don't want to use the battleship-gray dialog background then you'll need owner-draw.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**: I mis-identified the border as the default-button border. As David Hefferman pointed out, it's not. That is, I have now [reproduced that border effect](https://gist.github.com/4396146); when the program starts there is no border, but just a little mousing over the left button creates the border – at least in Windows 7.

Original answer follows:

---

The black border is because it's default. You shouldn't interfere with the system's visualization of default buttons etc. Users rely on those cues.

To change the font, maybe, like, WM_SETFONT?

Disclaimer: I haven't tried that. It might be you need to handle WM_CTRLCOLOR or something like that. Just try it out, and in the end, if the default buttons don't cut it for you, simply implement your own button.

Comment: No, the black border is there because of the non-default extended window style

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: it appears you're right in general. however, as [demonstrated here](https://gist.github.com/4396146) the black border doesn't appear until one mouses over the button, or click the other button (maybe also other ways). so it seems to be a bug. i misidentified it as a the default button border.

Answer (score 0):

I think the border you are seeing is because the button has the "Default Button" property.  If  you turn that off, then it will have a normal border.  The Default property just tells Win32 which button to activate if the users hits ENTER on the dialog/form.  If you only have one button, then it will always have the default property.  If you add a second, it will not.

The property is the **BS_DEFPUSHBUTTON** property, so in your CreateWindowEx call, you should be able to do something like:

```
Start = CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_TRANSPARENT, "Button", "Start", WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | BS_PUSHBUTTON | ~BS_DEFPUSHBUTTON, 20, 50, 75, 25, window, (HMENU)ID_START, hInstance, NULL);
```

If not, you'll have to set it with **ModifyStyle** or **ModifyStyleEx**, and pass it in the "Remove" parameter.  I forget which one the specific styles have to be passed in, but if I recall correctly, it's the normal style params, NOT the EX params.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this, but try creating the button like this:

```
Start = CreateWindowEx(0, WC_BUTTON, "Start", WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | BS_PUSHBUTTON | BS_TEXT, 20, 50, 75, 25, window, (HMENU)ID_START, hInstance, NULL);
        break;
```

It also might depend on how you've created your main window. Can you post the code for your main window creation?